# PyQt (or just QT). How to get QComboBox to fire a signal whenever it is set to a value (even if unchanged)

Tags: qt, pyqt, signals, qcombobox

I am using `PyQt4`, but this is general enough that it could just apply to `QT`.

I have a series of `QComboBoxes` that I fill from left to right (i.e. selecting an item in the leftmost will populate the next one. Selecting an item in that one will populate the next, and so on)

I am having difficulty getting my signals to fire under all situations (i.e. regardless of whether the current index changes or not AND regardless of whether the item is set by the user or set programatically).

More detail:

I rely on the signals of the first `QCombox` to fire whenever an item is selected so that I can populate the next `QCombobox` in the gui. I then rely on THAT `QCombobox` to emit a signal so that I can populate the next one.  And so on.

I want to pre-select an item in each `QCombobox` based on the user's last interaction with the gui.

I have a unique function per `QCombobox` that is responsible for populating and pre-selecting just that `QCombobox`.  The code looks something like this:

```
comboBox1.blockSignals(True)
comboBox1.clear()
comboBox1.addItems(sorted(itemList))
comboBox1.blockSignals(False)
comboBox1.setCurrentIndex(intLastSavedState1)
```

where `intLastSavedState1` is an integer that is derived from the text that was last selected by the user the last time they had used the app. I had hoped that the last line of this function would fire a signal that would cause the next combo box's function to load and pre-select an item (`comboBox2`).  And that action would then cause the next `comboBox's` function to activate and it would cascade to the next and the next.  But it is not working across all cases.

I have tried two versions of the signals:

```
self.connect(comboBox1, QtCore.SIGNAL("currentIndexChanged(const QString&)"), self.load_comboBox2)
```

and

```
self.connect(comboBox1, QtCore.SIGNAL("activated(const QString&)"), self.load_comboBox2)
```

In the first case, the signal will fire only if the `intLastSavedState1` is different than whatever is currently selected in the combo box. This causes an issue if the user had last selected item 0 from that list. In this case `QT` does not recognize my script setting the the current index to 0 as being a change (since after loading the box it appears to think it is already on index 0), and so the signal does not fire.

In the second case, the signal will fire regardless of what is currently selected in the combo box... but only if activated by the user. It will not fire when my script tries to set the current index programatically.

These appear to be my only two options regarding the signals.  So... is there another way of pre-selecting items in a `QCombobox` that will trigger a signal each and every time?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well... sometimes just the act of asking a question can lead you to a (partial) answer.

I have a work-around but I am still interested in hearing if someone has a better idea.

I am now programatically setting the index of the `QCombobox` to `-1` immediately after loading it up. Then, when I programatically set the actual index based on the user's history, it will always be considered a change (i.e. it will never be -1) and the signal will fire

using: `currentIndexChanged(const QString&)`

So my code looks like this now:

```
comboBox1.blockSignals(True)
comboBox1.clear()
comboBox1.addItems(sorted(itemList))
comboBox1.setCurrentIndex(-1)
comboBox1.blockSignals(False)
comboBox1.setCurrentIndex(intLastSavedState1)
```

and my signal looks like this:

```
self.connect(comboBox1, QtCore.SIGNAL("currentIndexChanged(const QString&)"), self.load_comboBox2)
```

This functions... does anyone have a better idea?

Thanks agian.

Comment: That seems reasonable to me if it works. Does this chaining method for restoring previous state provide an advantage over having a single restore routine that blocks the signals while you restore all three at once?

Comment: I can't restore all three since the contents of #2 depends on what was selected for #1. And #3's contents can only be determined depending on what was selected for #2, etc...

Comment: Same problem to me . But the above statement worked fine when i implemented it in a QWidget but when i coded in QMainWindow , the values of ComboBox doesn't trigger anything....

Answer (score 0):

You can check current Index of your ComboBox and then either call your slot or do call setCurrentIndex().

Example:

```
if comboBox1.currentIndex() == index:
    self.load_comboBox2(index)
else
    comboBox1.setCurrentIndex(index)
```

This way you will not end up calling slot twice.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me when I placed current index change AFTER connecting to the signal
`comboBox1.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.load_comboBox2)`
`comboBox1.setCurrentIndex(intLastSavedState1)`